# Impossible to do a flawless Azure VIP swap without any SQL errors

Tags: azure

When the site is being used by already a low amount of +5 users and I do a VIP swap I *always* get SQL errors, like:

`System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: Session Provider, error: 19 - Physical connection is not usable)`

I am using the `SqlAzureExecutionStrategy`. Also other requests during the VIP swap seem to take around ~30 seconds making the site really not responsive, *despite* that the staging environment is already fully warmed up.

- Is there any way to prevent this?
- Why don't I read much about this behaviour? Do others just don't care for a few broken requests and the slow 30s timeframe, or am I missing something essential in my Sql / EF settings?

Comment: I'm interested in this behavior as well.  I think transient fault handling takes care of this but still writes out the error

Comment: No it doesn't. I've encountered the error pages myself.

Comment: So my guess is that it's also a timing issue.  It seems to be closing the connections before it swaps the VIPs on the load balancer.
I would love to see if this is also an issue with Azure Websites.  I had opened a case with Microsoft about getting Server 500 errors when swapping deployments, but because I couldn't reproduce the errors with any kind of certainty, it was hard to troubleshoot.  Azure must close off the connections to SQL Databases before the vip swap happens, then opens those connections after... If you can reproduce the problem consistently, I suggest opening a trouble ticket

Comment: Hi @dcinzona. I'm definitely able to reproduce the problem. Never thought about opening a ticket as I'm just a small developer, but maybe I should. Can't imagine all the begin companies are just accepting this atm.

Comment: We schedule VIP swaps right now for off-hours, and it works for us technically because there's only a few seconds of downtime...that being said, this is an issue that should be resolved.  Do you have some source code that can reproduce the issue consistently?  I have a support plan with MS.

Comment: No, not really. It's a full production site where this is happening, but it happens consistently when I do a VIP swap and there are quite some users online. I do have a stack trace though, but nothing more interesting than what you see in the question above.

Comment: I maybe make an example, that would consist out of some db requests and doing a VIP swap, while a console app doing a lot of requests. Setting the environment up is only a lot more work than just the source code. So it's not really easy to just 'paste' an example in a forum.

Comment: understood, you think you could create a public github repo with the source example?  Obviously, I know this would take a lot of time, but it would help immensely when trying to troubleshoot as MS support could also look at the source directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally took the step to switch to Azure **Web Apps** instead of Cloud Services and all these problems have been solved, and even more.

It took a few days of time but it's definitely worth it to switch.

Paying for accidently leaving a Staging server on is also a problem of the past.

Answer (score 2):

You are literally swapping out live code while a site is actively in production.  You are definitely going to get a variety errors.  There is always going to be a split second where the services do not exist.  Same thing when you deploy a new sql schema.

What you need to do is realize that this is going to happen and engineer around it.  A strong dev ops team really shines here.  What I personally do is to do staged deployments in different geographies.  I will have traffic manager point all traffic over to the west coast web servers while I upgrade east coast.  Then I point all traffic to east coast while I update west coast.  I then set traffic management back to normal.

To allocate traffic from east to west, typically a single endpoint is set up with Traffic manager, which points behind the scenes to the correct endpoint, acting like a proxy.  Just remove the endpoint you are about to upgrade, which will force a redirect to a live site.  When the upgrade is done, add the endpoint back in.

You should also ensure that your code handles errors well.  For example if needing to sync with external systems and during an upgrade a single record is entered into your system but not the external, can the external system's state be rebuilt with your data, or vice versa.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your answer. I do not really agree with your point of view though. Azure tells in their documentation that it's just a simple IP swap, where the mapping of the external IP is mapped to the other IP - never any of the services should go down. So in a way they promise to do exactly what you are describing automatically. I don't see how this should influence internal communication within the datacenter.

Comment: That said I finally took the step to switch to Web Apps instead of Cloud Services and all these problems have been solved, and more. Web Apps is a great product.